# npm: ошибки при обновлении библиотек

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, install

при обновлении raect-проекта до самых свежих npm-пакетов через `npm install` вылезают ошибки

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"^5.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (ts-node, tsutils)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

которые исправляются `npm install --force`, но тогда возникают предупреждения:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm WARN Found: typescript@5.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   typescript@"^5.2.2" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin, ts-node, tsutils)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN   react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project

added 24 packages, removed 49 packages, changed 237 packages, and audited 1596 packages in 2m

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
```

**Такой вопрос:** Это нормально? `--force` достаточен для решения проблемы или можно как-то окончательно побороть эту проблему?

`--legacy-peer-deps` совсем не подходит, поскольку откатывает некоторые пакеты с нужных версий на старье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не то что бы это нормально, но такова жизнь. Обновляйте пакеты которые зависят от старых версий (если есть на что) или избавляйтесь от них. Или смиритесь с несоответствием версий у peerDependencies (если это ничего не ломает).

Как вариант перейти на pnpm и подменять версии зависимостей https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmpeerdependencyrulesallowedversions